# Multiple jumper cables to same GND?

Tags: gpio

Is it safe to connect the three cables on the right side of the resistors to the same GND on my RPi, or should I put them on separate ones? (I know very little about electronics, but I'm trying to learn.) Also how do I know how many components I can safely use on my breadboard to not damage the RPi, if there's a limit?

[image]

Comment: This question is a duplicate, and you only need one Gnd. Normal practice would be to connect the breadboard common (the row of holes with the blue stripe) to the Pi with a single wire.

Answer (score 0):

All the ground pins are connected. It doesn't matter which one you use.

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/ground

Use the power and ground rails on the left and right of your solderless breadboard. Connect the blue rail to one of the Raspberry's GND pins.